# Can we restore backup for standby from external hard drive with differnet drive labels

Tags: oracle, rman

I am using windows server 2003 and Oracle database 10g R2 and i have taken the backup using RMAN of my primary database in Drive label E. The size of backup is 1.5TB. In my standby database i don't have much space to copy the backup of primary database in standby machine. My standby machine have only space for restore the backup. i have copied the backup files in my external hard drive label G. Now i want to restore my backup using external hard drive label G. 
can i be able to restore it?
please share your experience and documentations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. The backup entries in the controlfile point to 'E:...', so after restoring the controlfile, you will have to catalog the backup pieces in RMAN by:

```
catalog start with 'G:\';
```

After this you can restore the database.

Comment: RMAN> catalog start with 'G:\'; RMAN> restore database; restoration is done. now after restoration when i alter database open it gives error. SQL> alter database open; alter database open * ERROR at line 1: ORA-16004: backup database requires recovery ORA-01152: file 1 was not restored from a sufficiently old backup ORA-01110: data file 1: 'F:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\CYBERDBN\SYSTEM01.DBF' when i recover through RMAN RMAN> recover database until scn 640699; recovery is done but when i start database SQL> alter database open resetlogs; it gives error " control file is for standby"

Comment: Physical standby databases are not meant to be opened, they run in MOUNT mode. You can open a physical standby database starting with 11g, but that is a licensed option (Active Data Guard).

Comment: Yes i know that. but for testing purpose we can open physical standby database as ` alter database open read only` ?

Comment: Yes, you can, but without `resetlogs`, because that is why you received the previous error.

Comment: i tried to open using read only but it gives the same error.
SQL> alter database open read only;
alter database open read only
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-16004: backup database requires recovery
ORA-01152: file 1 was not restored from a sufficiently old backup
ORA-01110: data file 1:
'F:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\10.2.0\ORADATA\CYBERDBN\SYSTEM01.DBF'

Comment: In this scenario you have to use a normal controlfile instead of a standby controlfile. You simply restore it from autobackup with `restore controlfile from autobackup;`. If you do not have an autobackup, restore it with `restore controlfile from '<path to backup\backuppiece>'`. Remember: run `catalog start with 'g:\'; crosscheck backup;` afterwards again.